# How can I run through this text file and use strtok() to extract numbers and store the numbers in a different file?

Tags: c, strtok

This is a homework problem for my C class. We are learning file I/O and I have successfully opened both files and now I have to use strtok() on the first file to extract number data and store it in a different file. I have successfully taken the numbers from the first line of the text file and stored them in the other file, but I can't get strtok() to run through the entire file. Any suggestions?

Not a whole lot...I'm drawing a blank here. I've tried to use " \n" so that the delimiter is both space and newline, but I don't think that it works...I thought that I could only have 1 delimiter anyway.

```
    void main()
{
    FILE *fp1 = NULL;
    FILE *fp2 = NULL; 
    int i;
    char strwarehouse[100];
    char *token;


    printf("Scanning files and parsing strings....\n");
    fp1 = fopen("Assign9.txt", "r");
    fp2 = fopen("numfile.txt", "w");

    if (fp1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR OPENING FILE, TERMINATING PROGRAM\n");
    }
    else
    {
        fgets(strwarehouse, 100, fp1);
        token = strtok(strwarehouse, " \n");
        while (token != NULL)
        {
            if (isdigit(token[0]))
            {
                fprintf(fp2, "%s ", token);
            }
            token = strtok(NULL, " \n");
        }

        fclose(fp2);
        fclose(fp1);


    }
```

Comment: First - do you have to use `strtok`? For parsing numbers from a stream, `strtol` is a far more efficient way to go. (and note, you only read one line with `fgets(strwarehouse, 100, fp1);` not the whole file)

Comment: Yeah the teacher wants us to use strtok(). That fgets line is from a for loop that I used to print the file to console window just for the sake of it (to see if it was working up to that point). It never occurred to me that it was only taking one line now.

Comment: Well, you appear to have the right idea for tokenizing the line.  Are you asking how to convert numeric strings to numbers?  There are many ways, but the aforementioned `strtol` is a strong contender.  There is also `sscanf()`, `atoi()`, and more.  But if you're just going to write the numbers back out, then do you need to perform such a conversion at all?

Comment: The first line (or line 0 if you prefer) in the file is "My house is 50.4 feet by 42.5 feet" and I have successfully used string token to store "50.4 42.5" in numfile.txt, but I'm having trouble going from the first line to the second (and of course the other 8 lines). I've taken the numbers from the first line, but I'm lost on how to go to line 2.

Comment: Then in your `else {` read each line with `while (fgets(strwarehouse, 100, fp1)) { ... }`

Comment: This wrote everything to the file. Thanks dude!!

Comment: Also note `isdigit(token[0])` will skip valid numbers like `-5` or `+10`. You may draw inspiration from [Parse Numbers From File](http://susepaste.org/70095129)  (link good for 30 days until Fri May 3 17:44:51 CDT 2019 `:)`

Comment: Did you write that code for me? Or just reupload? Either way, thank you. I will give it a read over in the morning. Can I ask if you have any suggestions on how to make it so that the numbers that are written to the numfile.txt file are formatted in such a way that numbers from the same line occur on the same line? There are going to be 10 lines with 2 numbers per line but right now I have 20 lines with 1 number per line. I don't want the answer, just a hint in the right direction. Thanks again.